# How do I convert a varchar in a table when there are multiple values separated by a colon (:)?

Tags: sql, varchar, type-conversion

How do I convert a varchar in a table when there are multiple values separated by a colon (:)?  For example, the data is listed as 123:234:344.  I need them converted into three different values to pull the information from another table.  Any advice, please?

Comment: Which DBMS? This varies.

Answer (score 1):

So you could use some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OtherTable WHERE OtherField IN (' +
    REPLACE(Field, ':', ',') + ')'
FROM Table

EXECUTE (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is always this particular format you can use this (for SQL Server):

```
select substring(field, 0, charindex(':', field)) first_part
,      substring(field, charindex(':', field) + 1, charindex(':', field, charindex(':', field)) - 1) second_part
```

For Oracle:

```
select substr(field, 0, instr(field, ':') - 1) first_part
,      substr(field, instr(field, ':') + 1, instr(field, ':', instr(field, ':')) - 1) second_part
from   dual
```